# Basic TPU Cross Shard Optimizer Not Working

Tags: tensorflow, tpu

In general, there are some good examples that use TF optimizers for solving general (non deep learning) problems. Given:

https://databricks.com/tensorflow/training-and-convergence
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/tpu.ipynb#scrollTo=a_rjVo-RAoYd

We want to be able to combine the two above and make use of TPU based optimization in solving high dimensional problems.

To that end I've got a simple colab code that does this merging the two examples above:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu import tpu_function
import os
import pprint
import tensorflow as tf

if 'COLAB_TPU_ADDR' not in os.environ:
  print('ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the first cell in this notebook for instructions!')
else:
  tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
  print ('TPU address is', tpu_address)

  with tf.Session(tpu_address) as session:
    devices = session.list_devices()

  print('TPU devices:')
  pprint.pprint(devices)

# Add this somewhere at the top
tpu_function.get_tpu_context().set_number_of_shards(8)

# x and y are placeholders for our training data
x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.placeholder("float")
# w is the variable storing our values. It is initialised with starting "guesses"
# w[0] is the "a" in our equation, w[1] is the "b"
w = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0,3.0, 4.0], name="w")
# Our model of y = a*x + b
y_model = tf.multiply(x, w[0]) + w[1] + w[2] +3

# Our error is defined as the square of the differences
error = tf.square(y - y_model)
# The Gradient Descent Optimizer does the heavy lifting
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)
optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(train_op).minimize(error) # TPU change 1





# Normal TensorFlow - initialize values, create a session and run the model
model = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session(tpu_address) as session:
    session.run(tf.contrib.tpu.initialize_system())
    print('init')
    session.run(model)
    for i in range(10000):
        print(i)
        x_value = np.random.rand()
        y_value = x_value * 2 + 6 + 5 + 3
        session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: x_value, y: y_value})

    w_value = session.run(w)
    print("Predicted model: {a:.3f}x + {b:.3f}+{c:.3f}x + {d:.3f}".format(a=w_value[0], b=w_value[1], c=w_value[2], d=w_value[3]))
    session.run(tpu.shutdown_system())
```

When I run it (in colab) as it is it just runs the first loop printing:

```
init
0
```

and then does nothing and colab just keeps spanning.

If I do not use

```
optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(train_op).minimize(error)
```

And other TPU features, then it works fine estimating the `w` Variable.

The questions are:

1. Why doesn't this work and how can we get the cross shard replicator to optimise this simple function?
2. How can shall I shape variable `w` to make use of parallel batches/shards on the TPU?
3. How can we make this even more efficient through use of an equivalent Dataset `prefetch` operation or using infeed queues?

The goal is to make use of `lower level` TPU APIs without TPUEstimator for example to help solve custom problems by leveraging the power of TPUs using the tensors , queues and shards only.

Comment: Same problem here, actually setting number shards using context causes training loop to be stuck

Answer (score 1):

1. It doesn't work because you are overriding the number of shards without actually splitting the calculations into shards. When I run your code, I get the following error:

   ```
   InternalError: From /job:tpu_worker/replica:0/task:0:
   RET_CHECK failure (platforms/xla/service/jellyfish/lowering/all_reduce_emitter.cc:832) replica_id < target.ReplicaCount() Unexpected replica id in all-reduce, replica_id is 1, target has 1 replicas.


   Error encountered while compiling %all-reduce.7 = f32[4]{0:T(256)} all-reduce(f32[4]{0:T(256)} %arg0.1), replica_groups={{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}}, to_apply=%sum.3, metadata={op_type="CrossReplicaSum" op_name="CrossReplicaSum_21"}, backend_config="{barrier_type:3}".
   ```

   It is trying to perform the computations on eight shards and combine the results, but it only has one shard to work with. Take a look at [tf.contrib.tpu.shard](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/tpu/shard). It creates a shard context using the given number of shards and distributes a computation over those shards. So, instead of setting the number of shards manually, you can define your variables as usual and then wrap any computations with them in a function to be sharded:

   ```
   # REMOVE THIS
   # tpu_function.get_tpu_context().set_number_of_shards(8)

   # x and y are placeholders for our training data
   x_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float")
   y_placeholder = tf.placeholder("float")

   # w is the variable storing our values. It is initialised with starting "guesses"
   # w[0] is the "a" in our equation, w[1] is the "b"
   w = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0,3.0, 4.0], name="w")

   # Wrap all of our tensorflow operations in a function we can shard
   def calculations(x, y):
     # Our model of y = a*x + b
     y_model = tf.multiply(x, w[0]) + w[1] + w[2] +3

     # Our error is defined as the square of the differences
     # Average across the entire batch
     error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_model))
     # The Gradient Descent Optimizer does the heavy lifting
     train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01)

     return tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer(train_op).minimize(error)

   # Shard the function so that its calculation is distributed
   optimizer = tf.contrib.tpu.shard(calculations, inputs=[x_placeholder, y_placeholder], num_shards=8)
   ```
2. You don't need to shape `w` to make use of shards, because sharding occurs across the batch dimension and you only have one set of weights for all inputs. You'll want to add a batch dimension to your inputs so that each batch can be distributed across the cores. `shard` assumes the first dimension is the batch dimension, but includes an argument to change it if your data is shaped differently. [According to the TPU troubleshooting page](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#batch-too-small), the ideal batch size is 1024 so that there are 128 samples per TPU core. If that is too big for your model, you can go smaller as long as it is a multiple of 128. Check out the above link and the [performance guide](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/performance-guide) for more tips on increasing performance.

   ```
   for i in range(1000):
       print(i)
       x_value = np.random.rand(1024) # Generate a batch of 1024 values
       y_value = x_value * 2 + 6 + 5 + 3
       session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x_placeholder: x_value, y_placeholder: y_value})
   ```

   Everything else should remain the same. I was able to train the model for all 10000 iterations. Keep in mind that for this simple model it will probably be slower than using CPU/GPU, but you should expect performance improvements for more complex problems with larger datasets.
3. I'm not familiar enough with Datasets or infeed queues to comment on this, but `shard` includes an argument for infeed queues so it likely has support for them. You might have to play around with it to see how it gets data to the computation function.